# set OFF all UISwitches except current in tableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiswitch

I need to that the user to be able choose just one value from cells.

```
@objc func switchChangedPeriod(_ sender : UISwitch!){
    if sender.isOn{
        periodUserString = period[sender.tag].periodUser
        periodSystemString = period[sender.tag].periodSystem
        //sender.setOn(false, animated: true) how to set OFF all switches except current
    }else{
        periodUserString = ""
        periodSystemString = ""
    }
}
```

Or maybe i need to set OFF just previous UISwitch?

Comment: Does every cell has switch and you want to off every switch except current?

Comment: yeah, every switch except current

Answer (score 0):

First create `delegate` for your `UITableViewCell` subclass and declare function for switch when it changes its value.

```
protocol CellDelegate {
    func switchChangedValue(_ value: Bool, period: Period)
}
```

now create `delegate` and `period` variables inside your subclass and also create `IBAction` for your switch when it changes its value

```
class YourCell: UITableViewCell {

    var delegate: CellDelegate?
    var period: Period?
    ...
    @IBAction func switchChanged(_ sender: UISwitch) {
        delegate?.switchChangedValue(sender.isOn, period: period!)
    }
}
```

Next let's create global variable for selected `Period` in your controller

```
var selectedPeriod: Period?
```

now implement your delegate to `ViewController` and set `periodUserString` and `periodSystemString` to right format and also if value is `true` set `selectedPeriod` as `period`, if switch is off, set it to `nil`. At the end reload data of your TableView

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, CellDelegate {
    ...
    func switchChangedValue(_ value: Bool, period: Period) {
        periodUserString = value ? period.periodUser : ""
        periodSystemString = value ? period.periodSystem : ""
        selectedPeriod = value ? period : nil
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

*... here you should consider if you need to set `periodUserString` and `periodSystemString` when you have `selectedPeriod` variable*

now set `UISwitch` states in `cellForRowAt` depends on, if `selectedPeriod` is equal to certain `period` in array with index equal to `indexPath.row` (notice that now your `Period` class/struct has to be *codable*). And also don't forget to set cell's `delegate` and `period`.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    ... // cell as! YourCell
    cell.delegate = self
    let period = period[indexPath.row]
    cell.period = period
    cell.switch.setOn(period == selectedPeriod, animated: false)
    ...
}
```

Comment: Don't use tags. They fail if rows can be deleted, inserted, or moved. There are proper ways to get the index path without using tags.

Comment: @rmaddy I'm just trying to use his solution, better solution would be using delegate pattern.

Comment: That won't work since a cell has no reference to its index path (and it shouldn't).

Comment: I noticed, but too late

Comment: You actually made it worse than using a tag. A cell should never know its index path. It will be just as wrong as using a tag if rows are deleted, inserted, or moved.